# No salen correos desde aplicación de Vercel

Tags: email, nestjs, nodemailer, vercel

Tengo un proyecto de Nest Js desplegado en Vercel el cual usa Nodemailer para enviar correos de un SMTP en GoDaddy, la cuestión es que desde local, los correos salen sin ningun problema, pero en el servidor, aunque sale un mensaje de servidor 201 diciendo de que se envió el correo, este nunca llega al destinatario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen es el log de Vercel al hacer las peticiones, una es un 204 que dice que se iniciaron las dependencias de nodemailer, y configuraciones de Nest, y el 201 tipo POST que es el que recibe la petición y envía el correo

De antemano muchas gracias!